# Trying to find the largest prime factor but I don't know what is wrong. Please give me advice

Tags: python

I don't know what is wrong. I am trying to find largest prime factor

```
import math
def getfactor(num):
    factors = []
    for i in range(2,int((math.sqrt(num)))+1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)

    return factors

def determineprime(num):
    factor = []
    for i in range(2,num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            factor.append(i)
    if len(factor) == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

factors = getfactor(600851475143)
primes = []
print(factors)
for i in factors:
    determineprime(i)
    if i:
        primes.append(i)
print(primes[-1])
```

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong?

Comment: The code is not working.

Comment: Learn to use a debugger.  Step through the code and figure out where it goes wrong.  You won't learn anything having us tell you want's wrong.  At the very least add `print` calls to display your calculations and figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
    determineprime(i)
    if i:
        primes.append(i)
```

to:

```
    if determineprime(i):
        primes.append(i)
```

The original version was calling `determineprime(i)`, discarding the result, and always appending `i` to `primes`.  The corrected version will only append `i` to `primes` if `determineprime(i)` returns true.

Update:  As Mark Tolonen pointed out, `getfactor` will return an empty list if its argument is prime.  In that case, the number itself should be returned as the sole element of the list.  It can just check to see if the list is empty before returning, and if so, append the number itself, since it must be prime in that case.

Comment: @fatihsarioglu164 There's still a bug.  Call `getfactor()` on a prime number like 101.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes that's true, it should add the number itself if in fact it's prime.